# How to describe the meaning of "framework" to a non-english speaker?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, synonyms

In computer tecnology, the work "framework" is largely used to describe tools, software, processes and even models. Examples of frameworks are: CMM-I, SCRUM, VueJS, .Net and Spring to name a few.

According to the Merrian-Webster online dictionary:

Definition of framework is:

1. a basic conceptional structure (as of ideas)
2. a skeletal, openwork, or structural frame
3. FRAME OF REFERENCE
4. the larger branches of a tree that determine its shape

For me, a portuguese speaker, the definition in the dictionary does not fit the above uses of the work *framework*.

What is the relationship between the formal definition of the word and the uses I presented?

Comment: This seems to me to be a question either about software engineering or Portuguese.

Comment: Not really, I know what a framework means in terms of software engineering (a set of integrated tools), however, considering the dictionary meaning of that word, I don`t understand the selection of the word "framework" do describe a set of tools. For instance, CMM-I is a maturity model, a description of behavior, however it is referred as "a framework". When comparing what CMM-I is with the meaning of the word "framework" in the dictionay, I can't see why CMM-I is named like that.

Comment: The dictionary definition that best fits this usage is (1), "a basic conceptual structure [as of ideas]," and I'd say it fits very well.

Comment: @TypeIA, alright, so I gather that any set of ideas somehow structured and organized can be named a framework. Spring is a set of programming tools, but behind it there are ideas that stablish the structure of Spring. Is that why Spring is a framework?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of words on the subject here:
[Stack Overflow "software framework"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964140/what-is-a-software-framework)

This reference to Wikipedia was found there:
[Wikpedia "software framework"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework)
"In computer programming, a software framework is an abstraction in which software providing generic functionality can be selectively changed by additional user-written code, thus providing application-specific software."

That's the first sentence from a longer article.
Maybe something from those references will help.

Comment: Thanks, but not what I meant. I know what a framework means in terms of software engineering (a set of integrated tools), however, considering the dictionary meaning of that word, I don`t understand the selection of the word "framework" do describe a set of tools. For instance, CMM-I is a maturity model, a description of behavior, however it is referred as "a framework". When comparing what CMM-I is with the meaning of the word "framework", I can't see why CMM-I is named like that.

Comment: It looks as if either 1 or 2 of the definition you provided are pretty apt. Similarly with "framework" synonyms: support, scaffolding, foundation, skeleton, chassis, scheme, shell... So, a set of integrated tools forming a system within which one can work, moving from one tool to the next? The use of "framework" seems like the obvious metaphor, just as language can be seen as a framework for expressing ideas.

Comment: Another question occurred to me. Are any of the systems you mentioned already sold in Portugal or Brazil? What term does the sales literature use, and what is its translation to English?

Comment: Well, the word framework is becoming more and more usual, exactly because it seems we don't have a precise translation to it. That became a problem to me when I faced the need to explain what a framework is without using the word "framework". I decided to prepare myself for someone asking me something like "why CMM-I is a framework and Spring is also a framework if Spring is a software and CMM-I is a document?"

Comment: Well, what about the Portuguese translation of some of the synonyms, "scaffolding", "skeleton", "chassis"?

Comment: "scafolding" seems to be really strange. As far as I know "scafold" (andaime) is that structure people use to clib outside a not too high building. In this sense, for our mental models, it does not fit. "skeleton" (esqueleto) is the inner structure of something that makes it to stand, like our bone structure. It has some relationship, yes, but it sounds a little off. "chassis" (chassis) is a platform on top which other parts are put and kept together. I can make the same comments as to "skeleton". (to be continued)

Comment: I guess what I have to understand about a "framework" is that it's something generic that someone made, but I have to add my own parts to make it work for me.